# I typoed a tag but didn't notice. How can I fix it?

Tags: support, tags

I tagged my question but spelled the author's name wrong. Because the first tag already has a tag wiki, I can't edit my question with the new tag. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For straightforward corrections like this (no discussion required), you can simply `flag` the question for moderator attention. Otherwise, a meta post is fine.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'll flag it next time.